# ASP.NET Identity uses ConfigureAwait(false), why is it safe?

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, asp.net-identity

Reading the source of ASP.NET Identity, I've noticed something that makes me perplex. On several occasions, I find that they use ConfigureAwait(false) :

```
/// <summary>
/// Create a ClaimsIdentity from a user
/// </summary>
/// <param name="manager"></param>
/// <param name="user"></param>
/// <param name="authenticationType"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public virtual async Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateAsync(
          UserManager<TUser, TKey> manager, TUser user, string authenticationType)
{
    if (manager == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("manager");
    }
    if (user == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
    }
    var id = new ClaimsIdentity(authenticationType, UserNameClaimType, RoleClaimType);
    id.AddClaim(new Claim(UserIdClaimType, ConvertIdToString(user.Id), ClaimValueTypes.String));
    id.AddClaim(new Claim(UserNameClaimType, user.UserName, ClaimValueTypes.String));
    id.AddClaim(new Claim(IdentityProviderClaimType, DefaultIdentityProviderClaimValue, ClaimValueTypes.String));
    if (manager.SupportsUserSecurityStamp) {
        id.AddClaim(new Claim(SecurityStampClaimType, await manager.GetSecurityStampAsync(user.Id).ConfigureAwait(false)));
    }
    if (manager.SupportsUserRole) {
        var roles = await manager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id).ConfigureAwait(false);
        foreach (var roleName in roles) {
            id.AddClaim(new Claim(RoleClaimType, roleName, ClaimValueTypes.String));
        }
    }
    if (manager.SupportsUserClaim) {
        id.AddClaims(await manager.GetClaimsAsync(user.Id).ConfigureAwait(false));
    }
    return id;
}
```

I understand the need to use it, but I'm wondering why it is safe for us to rely on the request context after using one of the ASP.NET Identity Methods - I'm assuming it is supposed to be safe since I haven't met any opposite guideline from Microsoft.

Do we actually have any guarantee that we'll be back in the right context ? If so how is it possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm wondering why it is safe for us to rely on the request context
>   after using one of the ASP.NET Identity Methods

Because only the inner task they're using inside `CreateAsync` will ignore the context. The `Task` created by your method, which may also be async and calls `CreateAsync`, will still capture the ASP.NET SynchronizationContext which will make sure you'll be right back in the right request context.

This is how async methods work, in general. If any inner task ignores the context using `ConfigureAwait(false)`, that doesn't mean the entire call-stack will now be out of context, it is only the implementation of *that async method* which discards the context.

Comment: Fantastic ! Thanks a lot for this insightful answer, you perfectly got what my blocking point was